# Matrix Manipulation: Subtract 2D Matrix and 3D Matrix in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, j

If I have 3-d Matrix like:

```
cor =: 3 3 3 $ i.5
   cor
0 1 2
3 4 0
1 2 3

4 0 1
2 3 4
0 1 2

3 4 0
1 2 3
4 0 1
```

and 2-d matrix like:

```
d  =: 3 3 $ i.5

   d
0 1 2
3 4 0
1 2 3
```

It is really simple to calculate in J language: putting "2 (by 2D matrix) after - sign.

```
d -"2 cor
 0  0  0
 0  0  0
 0  0  0

_4  1  1
 1  1 _4
 1  1  1

_3 _3  2
 2  2 _3
_3  2  2
```

But I am still a numpy novice....

```
cor - d 

ValueError: Unable to coerce to Series/DataFrame, dim must be <= 2: (59, 59, 59)
```

Is there anyway that I can manipulate this kind of matrix manipulation in Python Numpy??

Thanks in advance.

---

this is the python for loop code that I wanted to change into numpy

```
def pcor(df):
    cor = df.corr()
    n = df.shape[1] # number of indices 
    pcor = np.empty((n, n, n))
    d = np.empty((n, n, n))
    for x in range(n):
        for y in range(n):
            for m in range(n):
                if x==y:
                    pcor[x,y,m] = float('nan')
                else:
                    pcor[x,y,m] = (cor.iloc[x,y] - cor.iloc[x,m]*cor.iloc[y,m])/((1-cor.iloc[x,m]**2)*(1-cor.iloc[y,m]**2))**(1/2)
                    d[x,y,m] = cor.iloc[x,y] - pcor[x,y,m] # <-- this part!
```

Comment: What programming language is your code? This is not python.

Comment: that is written in J language, I just want to calculate those things in python

Comment: And of which dimension of the 3D matrix you want to subtract the 2D matrix? And of which index of the respective dimension?

Comment: I added the python code scotty! 
So basically I tried to subtract the 2d matrix from 3d matrix along 3d matrix's last axis

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to match the shape of d (currently (3, 3)) to the shape of cor (currently (3, 3, 3)) before subtraction. Try `cor - d[:None]`. This basically tells numpy to use the existing shape of d (`:`) and to create a new axis for the last dimension (`None`).

Comment: another way is to `cor - d[:,:,np.newaxis]` as you need to add 3rd dim to your 2D matrix